# basho_bench littered my cluster

Tags: c#, riak

basho_bench is the benchmarking/stress testing utility for Riak. Unfortunately it created a bunch of binary keys and the C# .NET API (CorrugatedIron) fails to delete the keys and also cannot delete the bucket. There are no Riak-provided administrative tools to delete buckets.  Any suggestions other than stopping every node in my cluster and deleting the riak directory, and then rebuilding the cluster? Here is my test app- I can post the C# code if that's useful

```
alexr:Release $ mono RiakFlushBucket.exe test
deleting bucket: test
*** [CI] -> ListKeys is an expensive operation and should not be used in Production scenarios. ***
deleting key ��+
deleting key �gu
deleting key �L
deleting key �
deleting key    �h
deleting key ��o
deleting key ~�
deleting key /�

Unhandled Exception:
System.Exception: Key cannot be blank or contain forward-slashes
  at RiakFlushBucket.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Exception: Key cannot be blank or contain forward-slashes
  at RiakFlushBucket.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
alexr:Release $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of corrugated iron replied on the riak-list. This is basically just a limitation of the .net client because it's trying to remain backwards compatible with http clients. Nuking the riak data on the server side is the best route.